# Constraint to one of the primary keys as foreign key

Tags: sql-server, database-design

```
Table1: grid_col (col_id,f_id,f_value) 
    (col_id,f_id) is primary key. 

Table2: grid (grid_id,col_id,text) 
    (grid_id) is primary key.
```

I want to have a constraint for grid that, col_id should be present in grid_col. I can't have foriegn key constraint here.
I can create a function constraint which scans the grid_col while inserting in grid but in that case it increases the chances of having deadlock.
How to add a constriant here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64645/discussion-on-question-by-dumper-constraint-to-one-of-the-primary-keys-as-foreig).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a TRIGGER on the grid table that will do an outer join on the inserted values and the grid_col table.This should give you NULL values for non-matched records which you can than remove from the grid table.